# Перестановка элементов в односвязном списке

Tags: c++, алгоритм, список

Есть структура:

```
typedef struct TSotrudnik {
    //информационные поля
    BigDATA ob;
    TSotrudnik *next; //указатель на след элемент
}TSotrudnik;
```

На основе структуры был создан односвязный список list на С++, список зацикленный, т.е. последний элемент указывает на первый. Нужно написать процедуру для перестановки элементов списка местами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать? Я уже запутался, постоянно что-нибудь не учитываю, и процедура работает некорректно. При перестановке нужно не перезаписывать BigDATA, а изменять указатели.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть *указатели* на ссылку на сотрудника, *идущую из предыдущего элемента*, покатит такое:

```
TSotrudnik* remove_by_link(TSotrudnik** pLink)
{
    TSotrudnik* item = *pLink;
    *pLink = item->next;
    item->next = NULL;
    return item;
}

void insert_by_link(TSotrudnik** pLink, TSotrudnik* item)
{
    item->next = *pLink;
    *pLink = item;
}

void swap(TSotrudnik** pFirstLink, TSotrudnik** pSecondLink)
{
    int secondFollwsFirst = pSecondLink == &((*pFirstLink)->next);
    int firstFollowsSecond = pFirstLink == &((*pSecondLink)->next);
    if (secondFollowsFirst && firstFollowsSecond)
        return;
    if (secondFollowsFirst)
        pSecondLink = pFirstLink;
    if (firstFollowsSecond)
        pFirstLink = pSecondLink;

    TSotrudnik* pFirst = remove_by_link(pFirstLink);
    TSotrudnik* pSecond = remove_by_link(pSecondLink);

    insert_by_link(pSecondLink, pFirst);
    insert_by_link(pFirstLink, pSecond);
}
```

Двойные указатели важны.

(А вообще, `TEmployee`, а не `TSotrudnik`, конечно.)

Comment: А если только ссылка на следующий элемент, то придётся потрудиться поискать предыдущие, которые на них ссылаются, и в них менять местами ссылки на следующие (нужные нам) элементы.

В двусвязном списке нужно заменять ссылки и на предыдущих элементах и на следующих за заданными.

Comment: @roach1967: В двусвязном списке легче, там есть ссылка назад. В односвязном приходится работать с указателем на указатель на себя.

@vvtvvtvvt: Обновил, вроде бы должно работать.

@avp: Может, вы придумаете вариант поизящнее?

Answer (score 1):

Если все элементы списка разные, то тривиально.

Обходите весь свой циклический список и запоминаете адреса структур у которых `next` ссылается на элементы, которые надо менять местами.

```
 swap(TSotrudnik *p1, TSotrudnik *p2) {
   TSotrudnik *pp1 = p1, *pp2 = 0, t1 = p1->next, t2 = p2->next;
   while (pp1->next != p1) {
     if (pp1->next == p2)
       pp2 = pp1;
     pp1 = pp1->next;
   }
   if (pp2) {
     pp1->next = p2; 
     pp2->next = p1;
     p1->next = t2; 
     p2->next = t1;
   }
 }
```

Не проверял, надеюсь нигде не ошибся.

**Update**

Спасибо [[@Vlad](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), за обнаруженную ошибку. Действительно, приходится рассматривать частные случаи. Вот что получилось.

```
void  swap(node *p1, node *p2) {
  node *pp1 = p1, *pp2 = 0;

  if (p1 && p2 && // элементы присутствуют
      p1 != p2 && // это разные элементы
      !(p1->next->next == p1)) { // в списке больше двух
    while (pp1->next != p1) {
      if (pp1->next == p2)
        pp2 = pp1;
      pp1 = pp1->next;
    }

    if (pp2) {
      if (p1->next == p2) {
        p1->next = p2->next;
        p2->next = p1;
        pp1->next = p2;
      } else if (p2->next == p1) {
        p2->next = p1->next;
        p1->next = p2;
        pp2->next = p1;
      } else {
        node *t = p1->next;
        p1->next = p2->next; 
        p2->next = t;
        pp1->next = p2; 
        pp2->next = p1;
      }
    } else 
      puts("p2 not in p1 list");
  }

}
```

Надеюсь, что теперь будет работать правильно.

Comment: @avp: Хм. Вроде не пройдёт для случая, когда `p1` и `p2` следуют непосредственно друг за другом. Тогда `t1 == p2`, и код `p2->next = t1;` сделает что-то не то.

Comment: Точно, не работает. Вообще, мне кажется, что-то тут неправильно.

Если будет время, попробую сегодня поправить.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Может, попробовать так:

```
swap(TSotrudnik *p1, TSotrudnik *p2) {
  BigData po = p1->ob;
  p1->ob = p2->ob;
  p2->ob = po;
}
```

Если, конечно, данных не очень много, выполняться будет точно быстрее и надёжнее...

Comment: @roach1967: Последнее предложение в вопросе явно указывает, что трюк с перестановкой `BigDATA` не подходит.